# How to detect the specific child nodes (physics body's) from Root node(_physicsNode)?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics, spritebuilder

every one

I am working with SpriteBuilder and Normal COCOS2D v3.1.

Coming to my problem
Simply I have Root Node _physicsNode and it have a number of child nodes(1 to 100 all are physics body's)
and all child nodes are added to the mutable array,All are added successfully and shows in the screen.

Now When I Touch on any of the object (among all child nodes) how can I identify that?

In cocos2d v2 setTag or setName are using for this,
but I don't know how to approach in physics engine?

How to detect the specific child nodes (physics body's) from Root node?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: note: spritebuilder + cocos2d use chipmunk as the physics engine, not box2d

Answer (score 0):

You can get a node by its name:

```
CCNode* node = [self getChildByName:@"someNodeName"];
```

Node and physics body have properties referencing each other. So if you have one or the other, you can get the other or the one:

```
CCNode* node = bodyA.node;
CCPhysicsBody* body = node.physicsBody;
```

If you can find the node, you have access to the body. And vice versa.